# Is there a better way to write test statements in mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

In the code below I am trying to assure that a certain page was rendered after the user clicked a link. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to make this assertion or if there is a better way to write it, perhaps with another inner it statement. Can this test be improved in any way?

```
describe('User visits the main page and clicks the Contact link', function()    {
  const browser = new Browser();
  it('should render ok', function(done) {
    browser.visit( "http://localhost:3000",
      function() {
        browser.clickLink("Contact", function() {
          browser.assert.text('title', 'Contact');
          done();
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In BDD style `describe()` is supposed to describe **things** to test against. You would want to separate each assertions per pages to visit.
2. `browser.visit` should not be inside `it` statement. Place it into the `beforeEach` hook.

```js
describe('the main page', function()    {
  const browser = new Browser();

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    browser.visit("http://localhost:3000", done);
  });

  it('should render ok when user clicks the Contact link', function(done) {
    browser.clickLink("Contact", function() {
      browser.assert.text('title', 'Contact');
      done();
    });
  });

  it('another test', function(done) {
    // goes here
  });
});
```

You can add another nested `describe()` suite to describe page elements such as "the Contact link," though `it()` cannot be nested.